# How pub/sub with pyZMQ between two VMs

Tags: python, virtual-machine, publish-subscribe, pyzmq

I have two VMs (VirtualBOx, Ubuntu 18.04 and python-zmq) running within the same physical machine (Win10). Both machines are configured as Bridge and they can be ping successfully 192.168.1.56-192.168.1.65. I've followed this tutorial https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html, however, it doesn't work. On one machine "server", the data is printed, however, at the subscriber "client", it doesn't receive anything.

Have you tried this or do you know which could be the cause?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"Have you tried this or do you know which could be the cause?"*

Yes, a copy-paste source code ( used the same **<kbd>`Scenario #2`</kbd>**, as you did, having a solo `SUB` ) works fine, yet rather use the modified code template below.

[image]

---

### A `PUB`-archetype Publisher :

Using ZeroMQ v.2.11, py-2.7:

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

context = zmq.Context()
try:
    socket  = context.socket( zmq.PUB )
    socket.bind( "tcp://*:%s" % "5556" if len( sys.argv ) < 2 else int( sys.argv[1] ) )
    socket.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )

    while True:
       topic       = random.randrange( 9999, 10005 )
       messagedata = random.randrange( 1, 215) - 80
       print "Topis = {0: >6d}: DATA = {1: >4d}".format( topic, messagedata )
       socket.send( "%d %d" % ( topic, messagedata ) )
       time.sleep( 1 )

except:
    print "EXC'd here"

finally:
    "WILL gracefully CLOSE Socket()-instance(s) and TERM Context()-instance(s)"
    socket.close()
    context.term()
```

---

### A `SUB`-archetype Listener :

```
import sys
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

try:
    socket = context.socket( zmq.SUB )
    
    print "WILL start connecting: for further collecting updates from weather server..."
    socket.connect( "tcp://localhost:%s" % "5556" if len( sys.argv ) < 2 else int( sys.argv[1] ) )

    if len( sys.argv ) > 2:
         socket.connect( "tcp://localhost:%s" % int( sys.argv[2] ) )

    socket.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 ) 

    # Subscribe to zipcode, default is NYC, 10001
    pass;                             topicfilter = "10001"
    socket.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter )
    
    # Process 5 updates
    total_value = 0
    for update_nbr in range (5):
        string = socket.recv()
        topic, messagedata = string.split()
        total_value += int( messagedata )
        print topic, messagedata

    print "UPDATE: Average messagedata value for topic '%s' was %dF" % ( topicfilter, total_value / update_nbr )
      
except:
    print "EXC'd here"

finally:
    print "WILL gracefully CLOSE Socket()-instance(s) and TERM Context()-instance(s)"
    socket.close()
    context.term()
```

---

Your [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) experiment fails after modifying the `SUB`-side code on defining an invalid TCP/IP-target where the code cannot, for obvious reasons, successfully `.connect()`. Go get a read about the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64918425/how-configure-a-multiple-pub-single-sub-python-zmq-ubuntu).

Comment: I've created those files but still listener `python SUB-archetype.Listener.py` doesn't receive the filtered data from server `python PUB-archetype-Publisher.py`

Comment: Step 1: zmq.SUBSCRIBE, ""

Comment: @pepepep. So as you see in step 1 as @user366197 said, he subscribed using `socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter)`